# Why does the AWS CLI report `Credential should be scoped to a valid region` when I have set a region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When running the AWS CLI to try to retrieve some ECS task definitions, the CLI reports the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the DescribeTaskDefinition operation: Credential should be scoped to a valid region.
```

I have set a default region using `aws configure`, and it is successfully stored, since it is reported when I run `aws configure` once more.

Any tips on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when configuring the region in the CLI, you should set it in **lowercase**.

That is, set `eu-west-1` (or similar) instead of `EU-WEST-1`.